'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0
I have an MVC project in .net Framweork 4.8. A class library in .net standard. In the class library I have a resource file (some string data).
When the MVC web app tries to render the cshtml where some of the resource string are used I got the following error:
error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0
My cshtml
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="color:firebrick">
        <div style="font-size: 12pt; padding: 10px"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>@PortalStrings.Error_UnknownError</div>
        <div style="padding: 10px">
            <span>@GeneralHelpers.SystemNow</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

If the resource is read in the MVC app's controller, no problems.

Have you seen this and this?
